# What is the difference between void f() and void(*f)()? And what are all the possible syntax to write when dealing with function pointers?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, function-declaration

```
void F(void f(), void(*v)())
{

}
```

As far as I understand, the two parameters have the same type, both are a pointer to a function that takes nothing and returns `void`. What is these two ways of writing? If they are both the exact same thing, then why `void f()` is not popular as `void(*f)()`? The first one seems easier since it looks like how normal functions are written. Also what are all possible syntax someone can use when dealing with function pointers? Or where to find them? Here are some of the ones I was able to get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func1()
{
    std::cout << "func1\n";
}

void (*returnFunc1())()
{
    return func1;
}

auto returnFunc1_2() -> void(*)()
{
    return func1;
}

void func2(int x)
{
    std::cout << "func2 " << x << "\n";
}

auto returnFunc2() -> void(*)(int)
{
    return func2;
}

int func3(int, bool)
{
    std::cout << "func3\n";
    return 0;
}

int (*returnFunc3(long long))(int, bool)
{
    return func3;
}

void func4(void f(), void(*v)())
{
    std::cout << "func4\n";
}

void (*returnFunc4())(void(), void(*)())
{
    return func4;
}

int main()
{

    void (*funcPointer)() = func1;
    funcPointer();

    std::vector<void(*)()> v;
    v.push_back(func1);
    v.back()();

    returnFunc2()(123);

    returnFunc3(123)(456, true);

    returnFunc4()(func1, func1);
}
```

Is there any other syntax that could be used? I'm just curious.

For example, what is the meaning of `int (*(*foo)(void ))[3]`? How to read such statements? Or where can I learn about reading such cryptic statements?

Comment: It's so simple I'm tired of even writing this but I'll anyway- here it goes - declarations mimic usage. What can you apply indirection and then call - a pointer to function - duh (although technically you can call a pointer to function directly - which is reflected in the parameter list - because you can't declare a function there so it's a pointer).

Comment: They're both considered the same when used in a parameter declaration. Function types and array types are adjusted to pointers.